# Incorrect data is loaded into Teradata from oracle database

Tags: teradata, informatica

I'm using informatica to ingest data from oracle db to teradata.

Field 'A' in oracle is defined as number(28,0) and I have defined same field 'A' in teradata as number(28,0) in DDL level.

Value of 'A' in oracle- 2014051810000957464

After loading data in teradata...

Value for 'A' is showing as-
2014051810000960000.

You can see the difference between source and target data. Can anyone suggest what I can modify   to correct this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the datatype of the field in every component it passes through in Informatica? If you turn on verbose data logging what does it show for the value as it passes through each step of your mapping?

Comment: @NickW, thanks for your suggestion. I have kept the datatype as number(28,0) in all informatica components. I enabled use of high precision in session property and it resolved my issue.

Comment: Based on the precision it looks like there was a conversion to a Float inbetween